# swift API to convert smiles strings to 2D chemical structures

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

Is there a method or free api written in swift for converting smiles strings to the corresponding 2D structures?

I have used babel or ibabel with python, but how do i use it with swift?

Comment: Your answer is very specific and I dont know whether this is the right SE for this answer. Any way look into http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

There's no Swift-based API for cheminformatics at the moment. (And I'm not sure if it's worth doing.)

My suggestion, since you mention using Babel and Python previously, is to use obabel on the command-line from Swift [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26973384/131896).

The appropriate shell command would be:

```
 obabel [file.smi] -osvg [...]
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what methods some apps such as 'Elemental' use to convert smiles into the 2D chemical structures on the mobile device.

Comment: @James AFAIK, Dotmatics, the developer of 'Elemental' has their own cheminformatics toolkit. There are certainly commercial toolkits suitable for iOS.

Comment: @James I'm not sure about other apps.